# how to find the height and width of the image view when it is aligned center in android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-framelayout

here is my snippet of code :

1. ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageviews"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
   ```

now am get the image at center of the screen it is fine for me as per my requirement.

Problem:

Here Problem is i am getting some un used space top and bottom, how can i find the unused space ?

How can i find the brown color space

Comment: I think it is not unused space which might be transparent space around image.

Comment: What do you mean by brown color space? Have you kept the background of imageView brown? Or does the image have brown color?

Comment: background of the Image View is brown color .

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your issue? It would make the problem much more clear. And we can give better support..

Comment: Hi Mike can you please look at this issue  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992000/how-to-find-the-height-and-width-of-the-image-view-when-it-is-aligned-center-in