# how to find the height and width of the image view when it is aligned center in android app?

Tags: android, html, css, imageview

Here is my snippet of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/framelayouts"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviews"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

now am able to get the image at center .

**Problem:**

Here Problem is i am getting some un used space top and bottom, how can i find the height of the  unused space or height of the image or only the imageheight ?

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
private void getImageViewDimension() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        int actualImgWidth = mDeviceWidth -  mImgView.getX();
        int actualImgHeight = mDeviceHeight -  mImgView.getY();


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "actualImgWidth ,actualImgHeight:"    +actualImgWidth +","+actualImgHeight ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        int Width = mImgView.getWidth();
        int Height = mImgView.getHeight();

        }
    }, 10L);
}
```

Comment: thanx for your reply,  actually the black portion visible in the image
 in the top and bottom is not part of my actual image but it is visible when i  align the image to center,i want to know the actual image size.please help me

Comment: Your app development For Android Native, setImageview width,height = "wrap_content". Check your imageSize is equal or lessthen device size.

Comment: Yes, imageSize is equals to device display size. but when i align the image to center, i want the new size of the displayed image.

Comment: Sure above code will return for actual size what u except. Other the you set scaleType on imageview.

Comment: yes, that is returning height (actual image height + above margin and below margin(black color just check in  screen shot)), 
i just want to know the actual imageheight after aligning it to center(No need top and black margins height)

Comment: Ok with in above function u put this line actualImgHeight = deviceHeight-mImgView.getY();

Comment: Hope please don't forget to give up vote(check) this answer because it will help to some others.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Image height using below code.

```
final ImageView layout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviews);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (height > 0) {
                Log.i("TAG", "height : " + height);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanx for your reply,  actually the black portion visible in the image
 in the top and bottom is not part of my actual image but it is visible when i  align the image to center,i want to know the actual image size.please help me

Comment: @SrihariGoud can you explain more about this.

Comment: Actually I need to put hotspots on the image,
so, when I align the image to centre, the hotspots 
positions are changing, so I need the new image size 
when the image is centred, to calculate the 
new positions for the hotspots.

Hotspots = clickable parts in an image.

Hotspots are aligned properly when Image is set to Fit XY,
but not when centred in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the height and width of the Imageview using ViewTreeObserver. Try this sample app.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int finalHeight, finalWidth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageviews);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                finalHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();
                finalWidth = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
                Log.i("DIMEN", "Height: " + finalHeight + " Width: " + finalWidth);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But since you are using fillparent for your ImageView, you will get the entire width as the result.

Comment: thanx for your reply,  actually the black portion visible in the image
 in the top and bottom is not part of my actual image but it is visible when i  align the image to center,i want to know the actual image size.please help me